# Android decompressing PNGs, will cause potential out of memory errors

Tags: android, background-image, out-of-memory, memory-consumption

I am using some png images for the backgrounds of activities in my application. These png files are mostly very small sized images. For example, I am using one with the size of 768x1024 which is actually 29.6KB on disk. When I run the application on my Samsung Note 1, I realized that the image actually consumes approx. 3MB of memory. So, Android seems to decompress the PNG file into a full ARGB bitmap (768x1024x4 bytes). I thought that this may be the result of the need of Android to resample/resize the image and placed the PNG file into the drawable-nodpi folder but this resulted in the same amount of memory consumption.

So, what should I do in this case, can I prevent this decompression behavior somehow? I have to put many different images for numerous activities in this project, so it seems that at a point this will cause out of memory errors. I am a beginner in Android and I don't know exactly how the system handles image resources, so I may miss something here.

Comment: Any image must be decompressed to be shown, so you cannot prevent the decompression behavior. There are many techniques clear the memory used by the bitmaps, cache them, etc. Most of them are described in http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these 2 lines to the  `in to the application tag` in the manifest

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

But these are not recommended if you are building a memory efficient App,
But this really works.